# if input contains any word in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, indexof

I have an input and I want to know if any of the values in my array exist.  For a simple example my array is

```
var _array = ["sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat"];
```

I've figured out how to trigger it if I type simply 'sun' for example, but I want to know if 'hhsun' or 'sunee' exist too.

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
    var _val = $(this).val();
    $('p').text(_val);

    var _array = ["sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat"];

    if (_array.indexOf(_val) != -1) {
        $('span').text('it worked');
    } else {
        $('span').text(_array.indexOf(_val));
    } 
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nosfan1019/WLacb/1/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check to see if an element of `_array` is a substring of the textbox's text:

```
var _array = ["sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat"];

for (var i = 0; i < _array.length; i++) {
    if (_val.indexOf(_array[i]) != -1) {
        $('span').text('it worked');
        return;
    }
}

$('span').text('nothing');
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WLacb/3/**

---

A slightly more obscure solution would be with regex:

```
if (/sun|mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat/ig.test(_val)) {
    $('span').text('it worked');
} else {
    $('span').text('nothing');
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WLacb/9/**

Comment: Thanks Blender, you've helped me again :)

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this is to use the built in [jquery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) command to loop through each element of the array and check if it is in the textbox value.

http://jsfiddle.net/WLacb/10/

```
$('span').text(-1);
$.each(_array, function(key, value) {
    if (_val.indexOf(value) != -1) {
        $('span').text('it worked');
    }
});
```

Comment: tough to choose, this one is a little simpler though