# JS/Jquery - if input has any name of an array, return associated value

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, associative-array

This is a continuation of a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965183/if-input-contains-any-word-in-array/11965237#comment15946964_11965237) I asked yesterday, where I asked how to determine if the input matches any portion of an array's element ('sun' & 'sunday' = 'sun').  Here was the solution.

```
var _array = ["sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat"];

for (var i = 0; i < _array.length; i++) {
    if (_val.indexOf(_array[i]) != -1) {
        $('span').text('it worked');
        return;
     }
}

$('span').text('nothing');
```

I just realized however that, if true, I need to match it with the full name value in an associative array.  Ex: if you type ('sun','sund','sunda', or 'sunday') it returns 'sunday'.  Ideally it would be case insensitive, but I can figure that out on my own.

```
var _array = {
    "sun" : "sunday",
    "mon" : "monday",
    "tue" : "tuesday",
    "wed" : "wednesday",
    "thu" : "thursday",
    "fri" : "friday",
    "sat" : "saturday"   
};
```

Here is the [second part](http://jsfiddle.net/nosfan1019/j2u5K/4/) of the solution.  I realize I could just remove the `else {
        $('p').text('');
    }` in this example but that won't work in my project code.

Comment: Please put all of the code into the question.  It makes the question stand on its own. External sites may not be around in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i udnerstand from your previous question, if any part of the text input matches an item in the array, then it is considered a matched.

Now it seems that you want to map the short array version to a full word.

If this sounds right, you can just get the short value from the Array, and create a map of short to long versions.

```
var map = {
   sun: "sunday",
   mon: "monday",
   tue: "tuesday",
   wed: "wednesday",
   thu: "thursday",
   fri: "friday",
   sat: "saturday"
};
```

Then get the array value, and pass it as the key to the map.

```
var _array = ["sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat"];

_val = _val.toLowerCase();

for (var i = 0; i < _array.length; i++) {
    if (_val.indexOf(_array[i]) != -1) {
        $('span').text('it worked');
        alert(map[_array[i]]);  
        return;
     }
}
```

You also said you want it case insensitive, so I added toLowerCase() to _val.

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong index in the map. It should be `alert(map[_array[i]]);` http://jsfiddle.net/DQPx7/4/

Comment: Looks good but be sure to put the `map` and the `_array` outside the keyup event handler because you don't need to make them on every event.

Answer (score 1):

```
function parseDay(val) {
    val = val.toLowerCase();
    var days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];
    for (var i = 0; i < days.length; i++)
        if (days[i].indexOf(val) == 0)
            return days[i];
}

parseDay('sun'); // 'sunday'
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use `.match()`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/t5pP8/